# SFML Events not displaying?

Tags: c++, sfml, keyboard-events

The Events feature in my SFML program is not working. General structure of main() is below. I want to register the last key pressed and switch screens accordingly. I know below would require the key remainpressed, but even doing so as a test isn't working.

What syntax am I missing? The tutorials and sample code I've seen on forums have made it seem as straightforward as below. I have seen switch used on keycodes, but that seemed more for instantaneous response in video games.

```
int main()
{

    srand (time(NULL));

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SIZE, SIZE), "Curling Party");

    window.setFramerateLimit(30);

   ...

    while(window.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Event event;

        window.pollEvent(event);

        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Q)

        {

            window.close();
            break;
        }

        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R)

        {


            ...

            window.display();

        }


        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::B)

        {

            ...

            window.display();

        }

        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
        {
           ...
        }


        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        window.draw(house[0]);
        window.draw(house[1]);
        window.draw(house[2]);
        window.draw(house[3]);

        window.display();

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.pollEvent(event)` should be in a while loop as the [documentation says](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-window.php):

> A mistake that people often make is to forget the event loop, simply because they don't yet care about handling events (they use real-time inputs instead). Without an event loop, the window will become unresponsive. It is important to note that the event loop has two roles: in addition to providing events to the user, it gives the window a chance to process its internal events too, which is required so that it can react to move or resize user actions.

Altought `window.display()` should be called only at the end of the window loop, you don't need display the window after every key is pressed.

Comment: How should I implement a "last key pressed" event? Am I correct in saying that a KeyPressed event will only run if the key remains pressed?

Comment: If you need real time events use `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::KeyYouNeed)`, but you always need the event loop.